# Trying to avoid Subquery in the Select Statement : Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-query-builder

**I am using Laravel 5.1. below is my Database query**

```
\App\Models\Project\Bids\ProjectBid_Model
::with(['Project' => function($query){
    $query->where('WhoCreatedTheProject', 16);
}])
->where('ProjectBidID', 1)
->where('FreelancerAwardedProjectStatusID', \App\ProjectStatus::InProgress)
->first()
```

### **What's the Question ?**

In the below part, if there exists no record, then the `Project Object` will be `null`. This seems a sub query in the select statement. Is there any way to return overall no record if 'WhoCreatedTheProject`value does not match in the database ? I meant I am looking for`Inner Join`.

```
::with(['Project' => function($query){
    $query->where('WhoCreatedTheProject', 16);
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this this way (you will have one query):

```
\App\Models\Project\Bids\ProjectBid_Model
::selectRaw('projectbid_table.*')
->join('projects_table','projectbid_table.project_id','=','project_table.project_id')
->where('WhoCreatedTheProject',16);
->where('ProjectBidID', 1)
->where('FreelancerAwardedProjectStatusID', \App\ProjectStatus::InProgress)
->first();
```

You need to of course alter table names in `join` to match your values.

But answering the question, in your example any subquery won't be run. You are getting all the project bids (this is 1st query) and later in separate query you get all the projects for this bids for which `WhoCreatedTheProject = 16` (this is 2nd query). So this what you showed is something different what you want to probably achieve.